# MVC3 form textbox values and FormCollection Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have several Textboxes generated via a foreach in the view.
To make each textbox unique I appended the item's ID to the name and id of the textbox.
Using Ajax.BeginForm to post to a controller with a submit button...

On the controller **I want to do "something" with the key/values**.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
...
        }
...

    }
```

In the end I wish to either send the values to an email or save to db but not sure **how to "parse" and format these key value pairs**.  The textBoxes are PartNumber and Price but the number of parts are generated dynamically in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have a list of strongly type model bound in your action method so u could write something like

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(List<Item> items)
    {
    }
```

you can consult Phil Haack's [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for model binding to a list. There are other bunch of articles you can find on this topic. just google "model binding to list asp.net mvc". you will find some useful resources on first page

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit more because my ICollection is coming up null.  Could it be because I had some hidden and calculated fields?